# Downloaded project will not run in an actual phone

Tags: android

I have been working on this project first in my pc at home. Since I am always not at home, I have decided to continue doing the project in my laptop instead.

I have downloaded the project from my Github. I just added a blank activity but when I run the program, there is an error.

Already rebuild and cleaned the project with no errors. Also uninstalled the app from my phone. I am just using the same android phone.

Build Error

```
/home/beverly/AndroidStudioProjects/Devcash/app/build/intermediates/instant_run_split_apk_resources/debug/instantRunSplitApkResourcesDebug/out/slice_0/resources_ap
```

Logcat

```
2019-06-10 15:18:09.641 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:09.641 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:09.641 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:09.643 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:09.643 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:09.643 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:17.646 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:17.646 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:17.646 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:17.654 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:17.654 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:17.654 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:23.372 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:18:23.376 914-1435/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) NetdConnector expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:23.384 914-1164/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) android.fg expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:25.649 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:25.649 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:25.649 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:25.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:25.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:25.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:33.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:33.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:33.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:33.664 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:33.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:33.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:36.491 914-914/? I/chatty: uid=1000 system_server expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:36.834 914-1735/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) watchdog expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:39.385 914-1390/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) UEventObserver expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:41.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:41.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:41.656 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:41.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:41.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:41.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:47.464 914-4082/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:914_19 expire 2 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:47.488 914-1617/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:914_5 expire 15 lines
2019-06-10 15:18:49.664 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:49.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:49.665 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:49.675 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:49.675 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:49.675 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:53.958 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:18:57.669 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:57.669 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:57.669 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:18:57.677 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:18:57.677 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:18:57.677 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:05.675 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:05.675 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:05.675 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:05.683 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:05.684 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:05.684 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:10.142 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:19:12.424 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:19:13.684 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:13.684 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:13.684 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:13.693 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:13.693 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:13.693 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:20.351 743-821/? E//system/bin/storaged: pid_info get_pids failed
2019-06-10 15:19:21.688 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:21.689 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:21.689 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:21.697 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:21.697 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:21.697 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:27.611 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:19:29.697 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:29.698 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:29.698 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:29.705 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:29.706 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:29.706 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:35.067 914-1416/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) AlarmManager expire 1 line
2019-06-10 15:19:35.092 914-3516/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:914_13 expire 4 lines
2019-06-10 15:19:37.700 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:37.700 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:37.700 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:37.708 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:37.708 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:37.708 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:39.570 914-914/? I/chatty: uid=1000 system_server expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:19:45.703 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:45.703 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:45.703 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:45.715 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:45.715 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:45.715 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:53.441 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:19:53.448 914-1435/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) NetdConnector expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:19:53.712 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:53.712 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:53.712 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:19:53.721 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:19:53.721 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:19:53.721 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:01.723 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:01.723 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:01.723 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:01.733 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:01.733 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:01.733 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:08.770 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:20:09.723 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:09.723 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:09.723 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:09.725 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:09.725 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:09.725 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:11.763 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:20:17.734 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:17.734 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:17.734 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:17.743 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:17.744 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:17.744 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:25.741 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:25.741 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:25.741 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:25.750 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:25.750 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:25.750 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:26.812 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:20:33.747 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:33.747 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:33.747 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:33.759 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:33.759 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:33.759 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:41.754 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:41.755 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:41.755 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:41.764 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:41.764 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:41.764 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:49.763 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:49.763 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:49.764 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:49.773 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:49.773 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:49.773 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:57.770 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:57.770 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:57.770 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:20:57.778 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:20:57.778 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:20:57.778 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:05.771 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:05.771 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:05.771 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:05.773 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:05.773 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:05.773 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:09.784 914-1390/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) UEventObserver expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:21:13.778 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:13.778 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:13.778 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:13.782 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:13.782 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:13.783 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:21.785 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:21.785 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:21.785 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:21.794 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:21.794 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:21.794 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:29.793 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:29.793 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:29.793 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:29.800 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:29.801 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:29.801 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:35.318 914-914/? I/chatty: uid=1000 system_server expire 12 lines
2019-06-10 15:21:37.799 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:37.799 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:37.800 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:37.806 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:37.807 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:37.807 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:43.764 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:21:45.805 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:45.805 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:45.805 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:45.810 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:45.810 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:45.810 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:53.815 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:53.815 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:53.815 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:21:53.823 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:21:53.823 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:21:53.823 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:01.816 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:01.816 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:01.816 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:01.823 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:01.823 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:01.823 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:09.827 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:09.827 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:09.827 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:09.836 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:09.836 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:09.836 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:17.831 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:17.831 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:17.831 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:17.837 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:17.838 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:17.838 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:18.833 914-1139/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) batterystats-sy expire 2 lines
2019-06-10 15:22:21.814 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:22:21.820 914-1435/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) NetdConnector expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:22:21.830 914-1164/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) android.fg expire 5 lines
2019-06-10 15:22:25.843 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:25.843 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:25.843 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:25.853 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:25.853 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:25.853 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:33.846 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:33.847 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:33.847 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:33.855 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:33.856 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:33.856 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:41.855 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:41.855 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:41.855 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:41.862 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:41.863 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:41.863 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:49.860 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:49.860 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:49.861 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:49.868 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:49.869 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:49.869 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:57.868 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:57.868 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:57.868 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:22:57.876 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:22:57.877 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:22:57.877 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:05.875 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:05.875 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:05.875 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:05.883 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:05.883 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:05.883 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:06.118 914-914/? I/chatty: uid=1000 system_server expire 16 lines
2019-06-10 15:23:06.124 914-1854/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:914_9 expire 1 line
2019-06-10 15:23:06.153 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:23:06.217 914-7041/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) Binder:914_1F expire 4 lines
2019-06-10 15:23:10.107 914-1390/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) UEventObserver expire 6 lines
2019-06-10 15:23:13.881 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:13.881 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:13.881 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:13.888 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:13.888 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:13.888 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:21.887 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:21.887 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:21.887 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:21.895 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:21.895 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:21.896 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:24.011 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:23:29.889 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:29.889 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:29.889 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:29.896 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:29.896 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:29.896 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:36.487 914-914/? I/chatty: uid=1000 system_server expire 10 lines
2019-06-10 15:23:36.862 914-1735/? I/chatty: uid=1000(system) watchdog expire 2 lines
2019-06-10 15:23:37.898 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:37.899 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:37.899 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:37.905 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:37.906 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:37.906 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:45.908 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:45.908 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:45.908 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:45.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:45.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:45.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:53.907 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:53.907 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:53.908 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:23:53.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:23:53.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:23:53.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:01.914 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:01.914 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:01.915 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:01.922 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:01.923 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:01.923 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:09.926 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:09.926 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:09.927 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:09.935 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:09.935 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:09.935 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:11.550 487-621/? W/SocketListener: sending broadcast to Pid = 914, Uid = 1000 
2019-06-10 15:24:17.928 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:17.928 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:17.928 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:17.938 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:17.938 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:17.938 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:25.934 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:25.934 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:25.934 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
2019-06-10 15:24:25.936 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_NOISE
2019-06-10 15:24:25.936 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_RATE_INFO_SNR
2019-06-10 15:24:25.936 746-746/? E/wificond: Failed to get NL80211_STA_INFO_CNAHLOAD
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is caused by "instant run" feature in studio 2.3, you can disable it by:

Open the Settings or Preferences dialog. Navigate to Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.